# Which countries accept the Pakistan international driving licence?

Tags: driving, where-on-earth, pakistan

I am a Pakistani living in Europe. Which countries accept the Pakistan international driving licence?

Comment: If you are _living in Europe_ as your question states, you are supposed to get a driver's license from the country you're living in. The international driving permit is supposed to be for short(ish) stays only, though as a practical matter you may or may not be able to get away with it.

Comment: If you consider UK as Europe, you may use a non-UK licence for up to 12 months from first date of entry.

Answer (score 4):

Example of Pakistani international driving licence ([image source](https://dnd.com.pk/how-to-get-international-driving-permit-international-driving-license-in-pakistan/157416)) :

[image]

It says "Vienna Convention 1968". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit#Countries_and_jurisdictions_that_recognize_IDP for the list of countries that are in this convention, i.e. that accept the Pakistani international driving licence.

Answer (score 2):

In most countries around the world, you can drive on IDP. Rules vary according to the country. Like in California you can drive for up to sixty days on IDP.

Comment: Do you have a source for this aspect of California law?